# Eliminar todos los backup items de un Recovery Service Vault con Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure

Estoy tratando de eliminar todos los backup items de un recovery service vault usando powershell. He encontrado un script pero este script elimina item por item esperando a que el primero se termine de eliminar para pasar al siguiente. Me gustaría modificar el script para, por ejemplo, ordenarle a Azure que elimine el item y pase al siguiente mientras el anterior se está eliminando. Intenté usar el flag -AsJob pero powershell no lo reconoce (lo tengo comentado en el código). Estoy usando la versión 5 de powershell.
Tengo que eliminar cientos o miles de backup items por lo que ir uno a uno no es una opción.

¿Podrían ayudarme?

```
## Variables
$rgBackup = Read-Host -Prompt "Introduce el nombre del resource group"

$vaultName = Read-Host -Prompt "Introduce el nombre del recovery service vault" 

$vault = Get-AzRecoveryServicesVault -ResourceGroupName $rgBackup -Name $vaultName

$count = 0
 
## ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

 ## Disable soft delete for the Azure Backup Recovery Services vault

Set-AzRecoveryServicesVaultProperty -Vault $vault.ID -SoftDeleteFeatureState Disable

Write-Host ($writeEmptyLine + " # Soft delete disabled for Recovery Service vault " + $vault.Name)`

## ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

## Check if there are backup items in a soft-deleted state and reverse the delete operation

$containerSoftDelete = Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupItem -BackupManagementType AzureWorkload -WorkloadType MSSQL  -VaultId $vault.ID | Where-Object {$_.DeleteState -eq "ToBeDeleted"}

foreach ($item in $containerSoftDelete) {

    Undo-AzRecoveryServicesBackupItemDeletion -Item $item -VaultId $vault.ID -Force -Verbose

}

Write-Host ($writeEmptyLine + "# Undeleted all backup items in a soft deleted state in Recovery Services vault " + $vault.Name)

## ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

## Stop protection and delete data for all backup-protected items

$containerBackup = Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupItem -BackupManagementType AzureVM -WorkloadType AzureVM -VaultId $vault.ID | Where-Object {$_.DeleteState -eq "NotDeleted"}

foreach ($item in $containerBackup) {

    Disable-AzRecoveryServicesBackupProtection -Item $item -VaultId $vault.ID -RemoveRecoveryPoints -Force -Verbose #-AsJob

    $count++

    Write-Host "$count - Item has been deleted"

}

Write-Host ($writeEmptyLine + "# Deleted backup date for all cloud protected items in Recovery Services vault " + $vault.Name)`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pude solventar el problema con este script, aunque puede ser mejorado:

```
# Powershell version >= 7.0
# Si al eliminar da error de formato de fecha, probar a lanzarlo desde una VM ubicada en North Europe en inglés ya que en algunas máquinas no da este error.

# Autenticarse en Azure
Connect-AzAccount -Tenant "[TENANT ID]"

Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId "[SUBSCRIPTION ID]"

# VARIABLES
[String]$rgBackup = "[RG]"
[String]$vaultName = "[RECOVERY SERVICE VAULT NAME]"
# $vaultId = "[RECOVERY SERVICE VAULT ID]"

$vault = Get-AzRecoveryServicesVault -ResourceGroupName $rgBackup -Name $vaultName

$containerBackup = Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupItem -BackupManagementType AzureVM -WorkloadType AzureVM -VaultId $vault.ID | Where-Object {$_.DeleteState -eq "NotDeleted"}

$containerbackup| ForEach-Object -ThrottleLimit 10 -Parallel {write-host -fore green $_.name; Disable-AzRecoveryServicesBackupProtection -Item $_ -VaultId "[RECOVERY SERVICE VAULT ID WITHOUT VARIABLES]" -RemoveRecoveryPoints -Force -Verbose} 

Write-Host "********************************* FIN *********************************************************"
```